# Average timedelta in list

Tags: python, list, average, timedelta

I want to calculate the avarage timedelta between dates in a list.
Although the following works well, I'm wondering if there's a smarter way?

```
delta = lambda last, next: (next - last).seconds + (next - last).days * 86400   
total = sum(delta(items[i-1], items[i]) for i in range(1, len(items)))
average = total / (len(items) - 1)
```

Comment: adding one more 0 to the end of 8640 would be a good start ;)

Comment: Why not increasing the earth's rotation speed? ... Guess you're right =)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Btw, if you have a list of timedeltas or datetimes, why do you even do any math yourself?

```py
import datetime

datetimes = [ ... ]

# subtracting datetimes gives timedeltas
timedeltas = [datetimes[i-1]-datetimes[i] for i in range(1, len(datetimes))]

# giving datetime.timedelta(0) as the start value makes sum work on tds 
average_timedelta = sum(timedeltas, datetime.timedelta(0)) / len(timedeltas)
```

Comment: +1  Because neither OP nor I knew that was a possibility. datetime crap is even more boring than strings ;)

Comment: I'll take your way to calculate the average and aaronasterling's to get the deltas. Thanks =)

Comment: It is not very Pythonic to iterate over indices. I would go with: `[a - b for a, b in zip(datetimes[:-1], datetimes[1:])]`

Comment: In this example it should be `datetimes[i]-datetimes[i-1]`

Comment: Clever trick to set datetime.timedelta(0) as the start value to make sum work. Also I note that np.sum doesnt work. It has to be vanilla "sum". But Franciska's method works too, and looks cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a list of timedeltas:

```
import pandas as pd
avg=pd.to_timedelta(pd.Series(yourtimedeltalist)).mean()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
from itertools import izip

def average(items):   
    total = sum((next - last).seconds + (next - last).days * 86400
                for next, last in izip(items[1:], items))
     return total / (len(items) - 1)
```

In my opinion doing it like this is more readable.  A comment for less mathematically inclined readers of your code might help to explain how your are calculating each delta. For what it's worth, one generator expression has the least (and I think least slow) opcode instructions of anything I looked at.

```
  # The way in your question compiles to....
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0xb7760ec0, file 

"scratch.py", line 3>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_DEREF              1 (delta)

  4           9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
             12 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (items)
             15 LOAD_CLOSURE             1 (delta)
             18 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object <genexpr> at 0xb77c0a40, file "scratch.py", line 4>)
             24 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             27 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
             30 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             33 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (len)
             36 LOAD_DEREF               0 (items)
             39 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             42 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             45 GET_ITER            
             46 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             49 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             52 STORE_FAST               1 (total)

  5          55 LOAD_FAST                1 (total)
             58 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (len)
             61 LOAD_DEREF               0 (items)
             64 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             67 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             70 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
             71 BINARY_DIVIDE       
             72 STORE_FAST               2 (average)
             75 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             78 RETURN_VALUE        
None
#
#doing it with just one generator expression and itertools...

  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0xb777eec0, file "scratch.py", line 4>)
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0

  5           9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (izip)
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (items)
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             18 SLICE+1             
             19 LOAD_FAST                0 (items)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             25 GET_ITER            
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             29 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             32 STORE_FAST               1 (total)

  6          35 LOAD_FAST                1 (total)
             38 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (len)
             41 LOAD_FAST                0 (items)
             44 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             47 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             50 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
             51 BINARY_DIVIDE       
             52 RETURN_VALUE        
None
```

In particular, dropping the lambda allows us to avoid making a closure, building a tuple and loading two closures. Five functions get called either way. Of course this sort of concern with performance is sort of ridiculous but it is nice to know what's going on under the hood. The most important thing is readability and I think that doing it this way scores high on that as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's much better. Thanks!

Comment: @shinn, if you accept THC4k`s answer, then I can delete this one.

Comment: You shouldn't delete it. I like the way with izip.

Comment: Indents do not match! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(timedelta_list ,datetime.timedelta())
```