# How to calculate average of seconds & milliseconds in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timedelta

My data is in the format of HH:MM:SS.milliseconds. How can I calculate average of such data in Python? I need average in form of miliseconds. I looked at several other similar postings but they do not answer my question.

```
My data =  0:00:00.618000
           0:00:00.593000
           0:00:00.569000
           0:00:00.572000
           0:00:00.636000
           0:00:01
           0:00:01
           0:00:00.546000
           0:00:00.400000
```

Comment: First, your format has microseconds, not milliseconds (even though the last three digits are always 0, so they might as well be millis).

Comment: Anyway: Convert them into `datetime.timedelta` objects, or integer microseconds or milliseconds, or float seconds, or any other type that can do basic arithmetic, and then you can average them the same way you'd average anything else: either with `statistics.mean`, or just `sum(times) / len(times)`.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: convert everything to pure millisecond representation

Comment: Also, why have you tagged this with both -3.x and -2.7? Do you actually need code that works in both?

Comment: @abarnert: I will try what you have suggested. I am a beginner in python. No, I don't want code in 3.x just in 2.7. I mistakely tagged 3.x. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @OferSadan: I tried searching for conversion, I am beginner in Python. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know you data size or if you require a built-in solution or not.

However, one simple solution involves using `pandas`. If you have

```
mydata = ["0:00:00.618000",
          "0:00:00.593000",
          "0:00:00.569000",
          "0:00:00.572000",
          "0:00:00.636000",
          "0:00:01",
          "0:00:01",
          "0:00:00.546000",
          "0:00:00.400000"]
```

You can use `pd.to_timedelta` and `mean` and just do

```
pd.Series(pd.to_timedelta(mydata)).mean()
```

Might be/might not be overkill, but its really readable and straightforward.

Comment: RafaelC: Thank you. Can we do something similar in list?

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself, I'd recommend @abarnert 's answer :)

Comment: @A.S This code already takes a list, and if you need the result to be a list instead of a `Series`, you can just call `list` on it.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to parse all those timestamps into something that you can perform arithmetic on. This can be [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) objects, or integer microseconds (or milliseconds, since your times all have 0 micros), or float seconds, or any other reasonable type.

For example, assuming that input is one big string:

```
ts = []
for h, m, s, u in re.findall(r'(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?', bigstring):
    h, m, s = int(h), int(m), int(s)
    u = int(u) if u else 0
    ts.append(datetime.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s, microseconds=u))
```

If it's a list of strings, or a file object, etc. just change it to iterate that and do `re.search` on each one, instead of iterating `re.findall`.

Then we can average them the same as any other values:

```
sum(ts, datetime.timedelta()) / len(ts)
```

Since I used `timedelta` values, that's what the result will be:

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 659333)
```

… or, if you `print` it:

```
0:00:00.659333
```

… or, if you want it as, say, a number of seconds, just call its `total_seconds()` method:

```
0.659333
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that each of these is a string, you can do the following using no libraries in both python 2 and 3

```
def mean(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)

def timestamp_to_millis(timestamp):
    hour, min, sec = map(float, timestamp.split(':'))
    mills = (((hour * 60 + min) * 60) + sec) * 1000
    return millis


my_data = # [ timestamps ... ]
my_mean = mean(map(timestamp_to_millis, my_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the input consists of strings. Those should be converted to [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects. Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to do that.

After that, the average of anything is calculated as `sum(values) / len(values)`, but unfortunately you cannot sum dates. What you can is sum date differences, so you'll have to make some conversions

For example:

```
dates = [datetime.datetime(1951, 1, 5),
         datetime.datetime(1951, 1, 7),
         datetime.datetime(1951, 1, 7)]

base_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()  # really, anything

relative_dates = [d-base_datetime for d in dates]

average_relative_datetime = sum(relative_dates, datetime.timedelta()) / len(relative_dates)

result = base_datetime + average_relative_datetime  # datetime.datetime(1951, 1, 6, 8, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using `datetime.timedelta`. The tricky part is converting strings into `timedelta` objects. Sequence unpacking makes this easier and efficient to implement.

```
from datetime import timedelta

data = ['0:00:00.618000', '0:00:00.593000', '0:00:00.569000',
        '0:00:00.572000', '0:00:00.636000', '0:00:01',
        '0:00:01', '0:00:00.546000', '0:00:00.400000']

def converter(x):
    if '.' not in x:
        x += '.000000'
    hrs, mins, secs, millis = map(int, x[:-3].replace('.', ':').split(':'))
    return timedelta(hours=hrs, minutes=mins, seconds=secs, milliseconds=millis)

res = sum(map(converter, data), timedelta(0)) / len(data)

print(res)

0:00:00.659333
```

Note that `sum` only appears to work with `timedelta` objects with the added `timedelta(0)` argument, this trick [courtesy of @JochenRitzel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617540/9209546).