# How to I calculate average time difference in python?

Tags: python, date

I have multiple times as a string:

```
"2018-12-14 11:20:16","2018-12-14 11:14:01","2018-12-14 11:01:58","2018-12-14 10:54:21"
```

I want to calculate the average time difference between all these times. The above example would be:

```
2018-12-14 11:20:16 - 2018-12-14 11:14:01 = 6 minutes 15 seconds
2018-12-14 11:14:01 - 2018-12-14 11:01:58 = 12 minutes 3 seconds
2018-12-14 11:14:01 - 2018-12-14 11:01:58 = 7 minutes 37 seconds
```

(375s+723s+457s)/3 = 518.3 seconds = **8 minutes 38.33 seconds** (If my hand math is correct.)

I have all the datestrings in an array. I assume it's easy to convert it to a timestamp, loop over it to calculate the differences and then the average?
I just began to learn python and this is the first program that I want to do for myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the time interval between two time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings)

Comment: If you want it to do yourself..I assume you should try out something..post code of what you tried..where are you getting errors and so on

Comment: The dup target will get you the intervals, I am assuming you can then do the average.

Comment: also, have a look at [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 4):

You have a bunch of problems. I'm not going to give you solutions to all of these. Just hints to get you started.

I assume you know...

- ... how to convert a time string to a `datetime.datetime` object,
- ... how to calculate the difference between two, i.e., a `datetime.timedelta`,
- ... how to compute a mean value (`datetime.timedelta` supports both addition and division by `int` or `float`).

So the only complicated step in this task will be, how to calculate the differences between adjacent items in a list. I'm going to show you this.

When you have a list of items, you can *slice* and *zip* to produce an iterator to iterate the pairs of adjacent elements in the list.

For example, try this (untested code):

```
l = range(10)
for i,j in zip(l, l[1:]):
    print(i, j)
```

Then build a list to contain the differences, e.g., using a *list comprehension*:

```
deltas = [i-j for i,j in zip(l, l[1:])]
```

Now [calculate your mean value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3617170/1025391) and you're done.

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects
- [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)
- [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5434891/1025391)
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions
- [Average timedelta in list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3617170/1025391)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

ts_list = ["2018-12-14 11:20:16","2018-12-14 11:14:01","2018-12-14 11:01:58","2018-12-14 10:54:21"]
dif_list = []
for i in range(len(ts_list)-1):
    dif_list.append((datetime.strptime(ts_list[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')-datetime.strptime(ts_list[i+1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' )).total_seconds())
avg = np.mean(dif_list)
print(avg)
```

result is 518.3333333333334 seconds.