# Median timedelta in list

Tags: python, timedelta

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617540/11736145), I can calculate the average of a list of timedeltas in Python.

```
timedeltas = [ ... ]

# giving datetime.timedelta(0) as the start value makes sum work on tds 
average_timedelta = sum(timedeltas, datetime.timedelta(0)) / len(timedeltas)
```

Is there a solution for obtaining the median of timedeltas in a list?

Comment: You could sort the list, then pick the middle value, same way you calculate the median of any other sort of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use statistics.median()

As an example:

```
import statistics

timedeltas = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(statistics.median(timedeltas))
```

importing statistics module, you can also use mean() (average value):

```
print(statistics.mean(timedeltas))
```

Comment: Thanks! The median works on timedelta, but for mean I get an error

Comment: Strange... Which error are you receiving?

Comment: `TypeError: can't convert type 'timedelta' to numerator/denominator`

Comment: You're rigth! Never used it with timedeltas before. Use your code instead for the average value which is OK!